# pandas get max threshold values from tuples in list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, arraylist, tuples

I am working with pandas dataframe. One of the columns has list of tuples in each row with some score. I am trying to get scores higher than 0.20. How do I put a threshold instead of `max`? I tried `itemgetter` and `lambda if else`. It didn't worked as I thought. What am I doing wrong?

```
from operator import itemgetter
import pandas as pd

# sample data
l1 = ['1','2','3']
l2 = ['test1','test2','test3']
l3 = [[(1,0.95),(5,0.05)],[(7,0.10),(1,0.20),(6,0.70)],[(7,0.30),(1,0.70)]]

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':l1,'text':l2,'score':l3})
print(df)

#     # Preview from print statement above

id  text   score
1   test1   [(1, 0.95), (5, 0.05)]
2   test2   [(7, 0.1), (1, 0.2), (6, 0.7)]
3   test3   [(7, 0.3), (1, 0.7)]

# Try #1: 
print(df['score'].apply(lambda x: max(x,key=itemgetter(0))))

# Preview from print statement above
(5, 0.05)
(7, 0.1)
(7, 0.3)

# Try #2: Gives `TypeError`
df['score'].apply(lambda x: ((x,itemgetter(0)) if x >= 0.20 else ''))
```

What I am trying to get for output:

```
id  text   probability                           output needed
1   test1   [(1, 0.95), (5, 0.05)]               [(1, 0.95)]
2   test2   [(7, 0.1), (1, 0.2), (6, 0.7)]       [(1, 0.2), (6, 0.7)]
3   test3   [(7, 0.3), (1, 0.7)]                 [(7, 0.3), (1, 0.7)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a pretty straightforward list comprehension to get the desired output. I'm not sure how you would use `itemgetter` for this:

```
df['score'] = df['score'].apply(lambda x: ([y for y in x if min(y) >= .2]))
df

   id    text   score
0   1   test1   [(1, 0.95)]
1   2   test2   [(1, 0.2), (6, 0.7)]
2   3   test3   [(7, 0.3), (1, 0.7)]
```

If you wanted an alternative result (like an empty tuple, you can use:

```
df['score'] = df['score'].apply(lambda x: ([y if min(y) >= .2 else () for y in x ]))
```